# Smooth looking way to count upwards?

Tags: javascript, php

I basically want to have a simple function or alike that would count much smoother than adding the amounts would be.

What I mean is for example:

53 + 39

Would just go to 92 instantly, but I'd like it to go 0-1-2-3-4-..-92 or from whatever start I feel like having. (I.E pre-set number 23, then count up to X)
How would I go about doing this? Preferrably in Javascript/PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop:

```
for(var x=53; x<=53+39; x++){
//do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of this and just changing the div with innerHTML, but I thought it would be an unefficient way to do it? I guess I were wrong?

Comment: The application itself, counting slowly instead of instantly, is inefficient for anyone that uses it.

Comment: But yes using innerhtml and a javascript setinterval would be a way to do it.